# Need help with MOSFETs to save battery power for microcontroller/RTC project

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, circuit-design

My goal is to wake up an RPI Pico using a DS3231 alarm which would trigger a DMP1045U MOSFET, then use a Pico GPIO to turn on another MOSFET so I can clear/set a new alarm on the DS3231 and save its battery.

Would this work? What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Mistake, R4 should be between GPIO and gate.

[image]

Comment: How is this waking up the RPI Pico?

Comment: The alarm from DS3231 should in theory trigger the DMP1045U and give power to RPi Pico and turn it on.